# How to print '-' separated items in python?

Tags: python, printing, fibonacci

I want to print Fibonacci series in the format: `0-1-1-2-3-5-8`
up to an Integer value entered by the user and values should be seperated by `'-'` in a single line.

Can this be done using print statement only ?

- By using **`end='-'`** it is giving '-' in the last.
- how to solve it by using sep='-' ?

my current code is:

```
A=0
B=1
for value in range(0,int(input())):
    print(A,end='-')
    temp1 = A
    temp2 = B
    A = temp2
    B = temp1 + temp2
```

Current output:`0-1-1-2-3-5-8-`

Comment: Make a list and use `'-'.join(list)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's actually quite simple: use a different **print** command for the last value:

```
A=0
B=1
for value in range(0,int(input())-1):
    print(A,end='-')
    temp1 = A
    temp2 = B
    A = temp2
    B = temp1 + temp2

print(A)
```

Also, I suggest that you disambiguate the loop limit:

```
limit = int(input())
for value in range(limit-1):
    ...
```